# Indirect quote without quotation marks, two spaces after comma?

Tags: quotation-marks

I seem to remember the usage of a kind of soft quotation, with no quote marks, but a capital letter and two spaces after the comma. Has anyone seen this? Does it have a name? Example:

> I asked him if it was possible. He gave me a dirty look,  No way.

Comment: 1. There's no such style I know of.  2. ELU editor tool trims consecutive spaces to a single space. So you may have had trouble trying to replicate your example in the body of the question.

Comment: How is that an 'indirect' quote?

Comment: @Kris On the first part, nothing in modern typesetting demands doubled spaces.  Regarding the second, that’s not necessarily true,    but    you   just   have   to    know   how    to      do        it            right.

Comment: @tchrist Which's why I said 'trouble'.

Comment: @Kris There are two spaces after the comma in my example. I used HTML special character kung fu, check closely and you'll see. I'm sure I've seen this somewhere, though of course it could be just a quirk of one author.

Comment: Pl see my comment reply to tchrist.

Comment: @Matt You don’t have to use HTML stuff, just insert the literal character U+00A0 `NO-BREAK SPACE` into the text directly. You may have a keyboard shortcut you know how to use, but me I always use ***murine snarf-n-barf*** for these tasts.

Comment: I've seen this, but I don't think the two spaces matter.

Comment: @Kaiser "I've seen this:" where? how often? seen used or seen prescribed/ suggested?

Comment: I've seen it used in certain books, usually when the speech isn't too long or important, and when the paragraph contains non-speech text. Maybe you want to paraphrase an entire conversation without using indirect speech, or maybe you want to describe a character's thoughts.

Comment: @Kaiser, In other words, you think the OP's example is fine and has precedents in literature?

Comment: @Kris: Ah, I don't think so, actually.

Comment: OP's question wasn't consistent with his example. In response to his question, it does have precedents. But his example seems a case of comma splicing to me.

Comment: @kaiser This: "usually when the speech isn't too long or important, and when the paragraph contains non-speech text. Maybe you want to paraphrase an entire conversation without using indirect speech, or maybe you want to describe a character's thoughts." is a really good summary of what I recall seeing. Any chance of a specific citation?

Comment: @Matt: The description is my own, so I wouldn't be able to give you a citation. And I haven't been able to find out what this style of quotation is called, if anything. But if you want to know if any reputable authors have used it, I would direct you to P. G. Wodehouse, who is generally regarded as something of a master of English. He uses it frequently enough that any book by him you pick up is almost guaranteed to have an instance of this.

Comment: If you want my opinion on how it might have come into existence, I would say it's one of those variant styles of quotation that writers who don't like quotation marks for aesthetic reasons started using. Another example might be the use of the hyphen or pointed brackets, neither of which I care for much. It's easy to use this style of quotation in sentences where the quoted text forms a part of a longer sentence, because these quotations are essentially embedded clauses. It's when the quotation stands alone as a sentence that it's likely to confuse readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is not standard in most formal written English, but has been used by a number of English novelists.

Novels have always had a history of stretching the boundaries of both the content and the form of language, and this seems to be a case of that. It seems that longer works make it easier to use such conventions, since the style is used consistently throughout the work. Here are some specific examples using your style:

[James Joyce, *Ulysses*, Chapter 16](http://www.online-literature.com/james_joyce/ulysses/16/):

> —**Was she?** Bloom ejaculated, surprised though not astonished by any means, **I never heard that rumour before**.

[Alan Paton, *Too Late the Phalarope*, Chapter 1](http://books.google.com/books?id=OoqNxmklHa0C&lpg=PP1&dq=Alan%20Paton,%20%2aToo%20Late%20the%20Phalarope%2a,%20Chapter%201&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> And the lieutenant said, **I did not recognize you, Stephanie.**

As a matter of style, I'd recommend you avoid doing this yourself unless you are the next James Joyce or Alan Paton and can convince your editor this is a good thing.

A couple notes are in order:

1. It's not possible in general to describe typeset works as having 'single' or 'double' spaces. Double spacing is [a convention that arose from typewriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typewriting#Typewriter_conventions) as a way to mimic the [spacing used in typesetting.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_spacing)
2. Many of the novelists who use the convention you describe also use it with the "[quotation dash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-English_usage_of_quotation_marks#Quotation_dash)", as in the example from Paton above.

There are other different quotation conventions too. In the US you find  “double quotes” most often; in the UK you often but not always find ‘single quotes’. [In many non-English languages you find «guillemets or angle quotes» or even „these unbalanced quotes or claws“ - [there are more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-English_usage_of_quotation_marks), but admittedly this is just an interesting aside.]