# Use of quotes when wondering

Tags: punctuation, writing-style

> You are probably wondering, “why is this so? Surely the soil is the same wherever you go!”

Is this grammatically correct? Or should quotes not be used here?

Comment: Grammar has nothing to do with punctuation or spelling or capitalization. Those are merely writing.

Comment: Apologies, I meant punctuation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you quote the actual question that the person is asking themself, as  you do here, it's fine to use quotation marks (only *why* should have a capital letter).

If you don't quote, it would be

> You are probably wondering why this is so.

Comment: [CMOS](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/244544/comma-quote-needed-before-quoted-material/304508#304508) is often happy to drop the capitalisation (along with the inverted commas) for internal dialogue. I prefer italicisation, with capitalisation.